# Flask-SQLAlchemy: Do I have to create_all if tables existed already?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

In the [example](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-sqlalchemy/blob/master/examples/hello.py), it doesn't specify that when and how to execute `create_all`.

> SQLAlchemy.create_all() method to create the tables and database

Suppose I have already created database and tables (also contains data already) in advance, do I still have to execute `create_all` ?

Answer (score 2):

No you don't. There are some advantages to using `create_all` in that you can quickly create production and test environments based on the database models that you have made. `create_all` also prevents having your models not match the actual database since the database was made from the models.

But if you already have the tables created and data already there, it is not required, although it is a good practice and had some advantages.